# Is it not possible to start a service of remote computer from visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I need to debug an applicaion.exe during its starup and the application resides on remote computer. If the application resides in a local system we can configure debugging properties of visual studio solution and use debugin->start new instance option to debug. Is there a way to connect to remote debugger and debug the remote process during its startup in visual stduio?

[image]

I have given the path remote details in the above properties but . when I start debugging(I am starting a new instance of the exe configured in the above picture to start debugging) the debugger exits because it cannot connect to remote debugger? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ّFollow these steps:

1. Run remote debugger in the remote server
2. In visual studio debugger properties, select "remote windows debugger" in "debugger to launch" option
3. Provide command ad arguments
   4 mention the IP and port in "remote server name"

[image]